# Bulk INSERT Tbl From @path

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, bulkinsert

I would like to do a bulk insert using a loop that will cycle through several hundred files.
But I can't seem to use a variable as the FROM path.
Can I use FROM @PATH3 or is there another way to BULK INSERT many text files?
Thank you

```
Begin
declare @days as varchar(2) = '06'
declare @path1 varchar(28) ='E:\WorkingTkr Data\_GDPD_02-'
declare @path2 varchar(9) ='-2020.trk'
declare @path3 varchar(40) = @path1+@days+@path2
--print (@path3)
bulk insert [dbo].[GDPD_Trk]
from @path3
WITH 
  (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
  )
  End
```

Comment: What's your database engine? Did you try with dynamic sql?

Comment: So sorry I'm using MSSM studio to access a  SQL 2012 DB. I did attempt a dynamic query which failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with dynamic sql, something like this:

```
BEGIN
  declare @days as varchar(2) = '06'
  declare @path1 varchar(28) ='E:\WorkingTkr Data\_GDPD_02-'
  declare @path2 varchar(9) ='-2020.trk'
  declare @path3 varchar(40) = @path1+@days+@path2
          
  declare @sqlBulk varchar(max) = 
'bulk insert [dbo].[GDPD_Trk] ' + char(13) +
'from ''' + @path3 + '''' + char(13) + 
'with' + char(13) +
'(' + char(13) +
'  FIELDTERMINATOR = '' '',' + char(13) +  
'  ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''' + char(13) +
')'
        
  exec (@sqlBulk)
END
```

Comment: I get this error:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 15
Must declare the scalar variable "@sqlBulk".

Comment: When I tried this I receive a different error:                                                                  ```Begin
declare @days as varchar(2) = '06'
declare @path1 varchar(28) ='E:\WorkingTkr Data\_GDPD_02-'
declare @path2 varchar(9) ='-2020.trk'
declare @path3 varchar(40) = @path1+@days+@path2
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
--print (@path3)
Set @SQL =
'bulk insert [dbo].[GDPD_Trk]
from ' + @path3 + '
WITH 
  (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '' '', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' 
  )'
  exec(@SQL)
  End                                  '''

Comment: error:    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'E:'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: I couldn't test, but it was an issue scapping the quotes on the @path variable. Can you try now?

Comment: I also forgot to include the datatype for `@sqlBulk` ‍♂️. Try it now, it must work. You just need now to loop over your days on your files. I have changed the dynamic query to make it look better.

Comment: That did it. I will play around with the + char(13) + to figure out what they bring to the statement.  Thnx!

Comment: @CarterWetherington, not big deal... just if you want to print your `@sqlBulk` variable get the output in a pretty way... it's a car return.

Comment: Added a simple loop to get a month at a time. It works great thanks Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @Jaime!  This is what I ended on with the While loop.

```
declare @Count INT = 1
  declare @days as varchar(2)
  declare @path1 varchar(28) ='E:\WorkingTkr_Data\_JCSO_06-'
  declare @path2 varchar(9) ='-2021.trk'
 WHILE (@Count <32)
 BEGIN
 IF @Count<10
Begin
  set @days = '0'+convert(varchar,@Count)
  SET @Count = @Count + 1
End
Else
begin
  set @days = convert(varchar,@Count)
  SET @Count = @Count + 1
end
  declare @path3 varchar(40) = @path1+@days+@path2
          
  declare @sqlBulk varchar(max) = 
'bulk insert [dbo].[Trk_HeatMap] ' + char(13) +
'from ''' + @path3 + '''' + char(13) + 
'with' + char(13) +
'(' + char(13) +
'  FIELDTERMINATOR = '' '',' + char(13) +  
'  ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''' + char(13) +
')'
        
  exec (@sqlBulk)
END
```